# Update the size of an NSCollectionViewItem when its parent NSCollectionView changes size

Tags: xcode, cocoa, nscollectionview

I have an NSCollectionView which has NSCollectionViewItem's as child objects. I have the flow layout of the NSCollectionView set the width of the items to fill the width of the view when the application is launched, but if I resize the window, the items stay the original width and no longer fill the view. Is there some way that I can have this resizing (fill width) happen automatically or is there a method that is called when the collection view is resized (from window resize) that I can access to set the width of the items to fill the view?

Answer (score 6):

All you have to do is to override the collection view class like this:

```
class MyCollectionView: NSCollectionView {
  override var frame: NSRect {
    didSet {
      collectionViewLayout?.invalidateLayout()
    }
  }
}
```

This ensures that whenever the frame of the collection view changes, it invalidates the layout.

Comment: crashes app when we do this with memory issue